# Magic Trackpad 2 loses connection after sleep when plugged in via USB-C/Lightning cable

Tags: usb, sleep-wake, magic-trackpad

Every time that I put my MacBook to sleep with the Magic Trackpad connected via USB to charge and then wake up my computer, it doesn't respond. I have to unplug it and plug it back in.

I've tried:

- Re-pairing the Bluetooth connection
- Another cable

What else can I try to fix this?

Running:

- Latest macOS
- [MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP799?locale=en_US)
- Magic Trackpad 2

Comment: Why are you using it continually connected?  Once it’s paired, just disconnect it and it should work fine.

Comment: @Allan to charge it...